# Group By With Avg gives 0 as AVG PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have following table

```
customer_id |   cust_name    |    city    | grade | salesman_id 
-------------+----------------+------------+-------+-------------
        3002 | Nick Rimando   | New York   |   100 |        5001
        3007 | Brad Davis     | New York   |   200 |        5001
        3005 | Graham Zusi    | California |   200 |        5002
```

I want to get average grade of city New York I tried my query as.

```
SELECT  Avg(grade),city from customer Group BY city Having city ='New York' ;
```

But I got this.

```
      Avg    |   City         |    
 -------------+----------------+
        0000 | New York       |
```

What could be possible fix for my query?

Comment: What data-type is `grade`?  An average of a numeric type yielding `0` wouldn't normally have 4 digits.  (Also, this shows that I can't replicate your issue as described: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=316a238d86b3f31382d155fa5cfa2c93 )

Comment: How are you running the query?  Perhaps the value is being truncated somehow.

Comment: [Works just fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fd59326e63a6043dda87f1655a41f433) (although I think you actually want `where city = ...` rather than a HAVING

Comment: My bad I used dumped data and grade had numeric data type with precision only upto 3.

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone finding this: **HAVING** is for restricting the result set by result columns that are aggregate calculations (e.g., `HAVING AVG(grade) > 100`). Use **WHERE** for result columns that are data rather than calculations.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your query.

I just tested it on my database with the following table:

```
+-------------+-----------+-------+
| customer_id | city      | grade |
+-------------+-----------+-------+
|           1 | New York  |   200 |
|           2 | New York  |   300 |
|           3 | Barcelona |   400 |
+-------------+-----------+-------+
```

The query `SELECT city, Avg(grade) FROM customer GROUP BY city;` returns:

```
+-----------+------------+
| city      | Avg(grade) |
+-----------+------------+
| Barcelona |   400.0000 |
| New York  |   250.0000 |
+-----------+------------+
```

And the query `SELECT city, Avg(grade) FROM customer GROUP BY city HAVING city='New York';` returns:

```
+----------+------------+
| city     | Avg(grade) |
+----------+------------+
| New York |   250.0000 |
+----------+------------+
```

You may have a wrong type for the grade column. Make sure it is a number.

Also you can use `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`:

```
SELECT city, Avg(grade) FROM customer WHERE city='New York';
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.  Please delete this answer and comment on the question instead.